# openpyxl ImportError in Airflow docker when using pd.read_excel()

Tags: python, pandas, docker, airflow, openpyxl

When using pandas pd.read_excel() in an airflow task inside a container I get the openpyxl error below. I tried installing openpyxl using poetry and even using pip in the dockerfile but no success.

```
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 521, in __init__
    import_optional_dependency("openpyxl")
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py", line 118, in import_optional_dependency
    raise ImportError(msg) from None
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
```

Here the versions in poetry toml

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.8, <3.11"
pandas = "^1.3.3"
apache-airflow = "2.2.4"
openpyxl = "^3.0.9"
```

Similar and recent issue is reported here:
https://dockerquestions.com/2022/03/02/docker-compose-airflow-no-error-during-build-missing-python-package-in-worker-container/
Any suggestion?

#### docker-compose.yaml

(don't forget to create .env, see comment down)

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build:
    dockerfile: ./docker/airflow.dockerfile
    context: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags  # laptop_folder:container_folder sync
    - ./airflow/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./airflow/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./airflow/scheduler:/opt/airflow/scheduler
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}" # echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0" > .env
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.2.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - ./airflow/:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

#### a docker folder with an airflow.dockerfile

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.5-python3.8

# use root for settings
USER root

ARG YOUR_ENV="virtualenv"

ENV YOUR_ENV=${YOUR_ENV} \
    PYTHONPATH="/opt/" \
    # PYTHONPATH="/opt/" -> python path to airflow-common volumes
    PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    LANG=C.UTF-8

# linux libs 
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    gcc curl libpq-dev \ 
    && pip3 install openpyxl pandas apache-airflow \
    && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 

# use airflow for r/w files
USER airflow
```

#### py file inside dags folder

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator



# pipeline setup
dag = DAG(
    'pipeline_etl',
    start_date=datetime.now(),
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup=False,
)

URL = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00352/Online%20Retail.xlsx"

def read_xls():
    df = pd.read_excel(URL,nrows=1000)
    return df


run_python_report = PythonOperator(
    task_id='python_report', python_callable=read_xls, dag=dag
)


start_op = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task', dag=dag)
end_op = DummyOperator(task_id='end_task', dag=dag)

start_op >> run_python_report >> end_op
```

Comment: So, to be clear, you have tried having the step `RUN pip install openpyxl` in your Dockerfile, and you still got the error you report?

Comment: @joanis yes exactly. I also tried COPY requirements.txt and than RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt but no success

Comment: And have you tried @Vinicius's solution? I.e., does it work when you run that same pip install interactively instead of as part of the Dockerfile? That would be really weird to me. Anyway, it's hard to reproduce your problem. Would you be able to provide a minimal Dockerfile that reproduces the problem with the smallest requirement set possible? Like the smallest Dockerfile with Python one-liner or script that triggers the ImportError you report, so we could reproduce your problem on our machines.

Comment: Add everything above

Comment: OK, so maybe it won't be easy to create a minimum reproducible example, but I'm not sure anyone here will be able to answer your question if you cannot provide one. If you can reduce it to a single image with the smallest Dockerfile that causes the error, a) you might find the problem yourself while creating that example, and b) others will be able to reproduce the problem, which is not the case now.

Comment: Just posted the RUN pip3 install etc. version. Should be easy to test the other two

Comment: Well, I'm not willing to try to run that much stuff, but I did something much more minimal: `docker run --rm -it apache/airflow:2.2.5-python3.8  standalone` in one terminal window, `docker exec -it aa2977b772ba  /bin/bash` in another, and there `pip3 install openpyxl` followed by manually running `import pandas as pd; pd.DataFrame().to_excel("foo.xlsx")` in an interactive python prompt worked fine. I'm afraid I'm going to leave it at this.

Comment: I could see what you're mounting in `/opt/` bringing in stuff that's external to the image, though, and potentially introducing conflicts since you're putting it on your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: @joanis it is quite easy to set up and Vinicius was able to replicate the problem (see below)

Answer (score 0):

Jump in inside the container and install manually

Getting the airflow server container id:

```sh
$ docker ps
```

Go inside container:

```sh
$ docker exec -it <id> bash
```

and finally install the package:

```sh
$ pip install openpyxl
```

Comment: If this works interactively in the container, it should also have worked in the Dockerfile, since that's (theoretically?) doing the same work, no?

Comment: @Vinicius I already tried your suggestion but no success.

Comment: @rpalloni I'm able to replicate this issue too

Comment: Ok! I could not find an aswer yet...